# How to display multilined formatted hashtable in a WinForms label in PowerShell

Tags: winforms, powershell, label, hashtable

I have a simple WinForms form object that has a label attached to it where I am loading text from a simple backend in the form of multiple hashtables (an array of hashtables, actually).

I have a text file that has information preloaded into it in the following format:

```
@{Key1='Value1x'; Key2='Value1y'; Key3='Value1z'}
@{Key1='Value2x'; Key2='Value2y'; Key3='Value2z'}
@{Key1='Value3x'; Key2='Value3y'; Key3='Value3z'}
```

which I append to a variable like so:

```
$hashArray = Get-Content $env:ProgramData\Path\BackEnd.txt | Out-String | iex
```

This allows me to handle the information as both a hashtable and an array (sort of).

Here is a mock-up of my WinForm for convenience:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = '850,500'
$form.StartPosition = [Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

$hTA = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$hTA.Size = '500,400'
$hTA.Location = '50,50'

$ht = Get-Content $env:ProgramData\Path\BackEnd.txt | Out-String | iex

$hTA.Text = "{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[0], $ht.Key2[0], $ht.Key3[0]
            "{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[1], $ht.Key2[1], $ht.Key3[1]
            "{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[2], $ht.Key2[2], $ht.Key3[2]

$form.Controls.Add($hTA)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

In that format, the only thing displayed is:

```
Value1x Value1y Value1z
```

I figured it could be a multiline issue with that particular control item (`Windows.Forms.Label`), so I replaced the assignment of `$hTA.Text` with a multilined `Here-String`:

```
$hTA.Text = @"
    Test1
    Test2
    Test3
"@
```

This displayed correctly, showing each line.

I attempted a drop-line escape character (`` `n ``) but that made no difference.

I'm not quite sure why it is doing this, so, I'm turning to SO.

Worse case, I could always create several single-line label objects and stack them on top of each other, however, I don't feel like that is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I realized it when I started thinking about how the `text` property reads delimiters to know when to end the property assignment.

Seeing as how there were 2 lines that hovered below the `$hTA.Text` entry, it seems kind of obvious.

What I did to make it work was this:

```
$hTA.Text =    "{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[0], $ht.Key2[0], $ht.Key3[0]
$hTA.Text += "`n{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[1], $ht.Key2[1], $ht.Key3[1]
$hTA.Text += "`n{0} {1} {2}" -f $ht.Key1[2], $ht.Key2[2], $ht.Key3[2]
```

Which displayed like this:

```
Value1x Value1y Value1z
Value2x Value2y Value2z
Value3x Value3y Value3z
```

I guess I could keep this here for posterity. Someone else is likely to come across with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done with a single format string, like this:

```
$fmt = "{0} {1} {2}`n{3} {4} {5}`n{6} {7} {8}"
$hTA.Text = $fmt -f $ht.Key1[0], $ht.Key2[0], $ht.Key3[0],
                    $ht.Key1[1], $ht.Key2[1], $ht.Key3[1],
                    $ht.Key1[2], $ht.Key2[2], $ht.Key3[2]
```

or like this:

```
$fmt = "{0} {3} {6}`n{1} {4} {7}`n{2} {5} {8}"
$hTA.Text = $fmt -f ($ht.Key1[0..2] + $ht.Key2[0..2] + $ht.Key3[0..2])
```